# r - read zip file from s3 using r

Tags: r, amazon-s3, sas, r-haven

Is it possible to read a zipped `sas` file (or any kind or file) from `s3` using r?

Here is what I'm trying:

```
library(aws.s3)
library(haven)

s3read_using(FUN = read_sas(unzip(.)),
                   bucket = "s3://bucket/",
                   object = "file.zip") # and inside is a .sas7bdat file
```

but it's obviously not recognizing the `.`. I have not found any good info on reading a `.zip` file from `s3`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Does your zip file has just one file in it?

Comment: @Tom yes it only has one file in it. In this particular case I the file was a `sas` file, but i think a `csv` would be more practical.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to read the zip file from S3 and store it in the local Linux system. Maybe you can try this and then unzip the file and read.

```
library("aws.s3")
save_object("s3://mybucket/input/test.zip", file = "/home/test.zip", bucket = "mybucket")
```